# How can I use one app for many subdomain with the graph API?

Tags: facebook, configuration, facebook-graph-api, subdomain

In my case I want to use one app to get some data with the graph API. Each of my users have a subdomain like http://user.mydomain.com. But when I set up my FB app I can only use one website in the section 'Select how your app integrates with Facebook'.

Is the wilcard working? (I mean http://*.mydomain.com)

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you put mydomain.com in the App Domain field, it will allow any subdomains from that domain to work.

Comment: ok, figured out my problem. Needed to put app domain as mydomain.com and SiteURL as http://mydomain.com (seem simple enough but somehow eluded me) http://stackoverflow.com/q/11932191/796437