# Facebook Login via PHP SDK v4. returns "Invalid redirect_uri"

Tags: php, facebook, laravel-4, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-login

I am trying to implement the Facebook Login to a site I have. The web application is built with Laravel 4.2 and I am using the `SammyK/LaravelFacebookSdk`.

I have the following code for the initial route that does login:

```
 Route::get('/facebook', function()
 {

      $login_link = Facebook::getLoginUrl(['email', 'user_status'], 'http://staging.breathe.yogijii.com/facebook/login/');
      return Redirect::to($login_link);

 });
```

Doing a `die` on the `$login_link` gives me the following string:

> https://www.facebook.com/v2.2/dialog/oauth?client_id=479112728894729&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fstaging.breathe.yogijii.com%2Ffacebook%2Flogin%2F&state=fd1c84414631fd179b3632f71cec9299&sdk=php-sdk-4.0.14&scope=email%2Cuser_status

The callback route (facebook/login) is:

```
 // Endpoint that is redirected to after an authentication attempt
 Route::get('/facebook/login', function()
 {
    /**
    * Obtain an access token.
    */   
    try
    {
        $token = Facebook::getTokenFromRedirect();

         if ( ! $token)
         {
             return Redirect::route('login')
                ->with('flash_notice', 'Unable to obtain access token');
         }
    }
    catch (FacebookQueryBuilderException $e)
    {
         return Redirect::route('login')->with('flash_notice', $e->getPrevious()->getMessage());
    }

    if ( ! $token->isLongLived())
    {
        /**
        * Extend the access token.
        */
        try
        {
            $token = $token->extend();
        }
        catch (FacebookQueryBuilderException $e)
        {
           return Redirect::route('login')
                ->with('flash_notice', $e->getPrevious()->getMessage());
        }
    }

    Facebook::setAccessToken($token);

    /**
    * Get basic info on the user from Facebook.
    */
    try
    {
        $facebook_user = Facebook::object('me')->fields('id','name')->get();
    }
    catch (FacebookQueryBuilderException $e)
    {
        return Redirect::route('login')
            ->with('flash_notice', $e->getPrevious()->getMessage());
    }

    // Create the user if not exists or update existing
    $user = User::createOrUpdateFacebookObject($facebook_user);

    // Log the user into Laravel
    Facebook::auth()->login($user);

    return Redirect::route('login')
        ->with('flash_notice', 'Successfully logged in with Facebook');
});
```

The code redirects to Facebook and seems to work fine. However when it comes back to my application I get the error:

> Invalid redirect_uri: Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.

I have looked over everything and spent hours on this. I am not sure if I am missing something small.  This is what my app configuration looks like:

[image: Facebook settings screenshot]

My App domains match perfectly.  I tried making a canvas app also, that also didn't work.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

I tried adding my redirect to the valid oaths... Still does not work.
[image]

Comment: It would be nice for you to say why the down vote so I can improve the question...  Thanks

Comment: If your redirect_uri was wrong, you should get that error message before the auth dialog is even shown, but that is not what happens. It allows me to auth your app, and then redirects back to it. (And then your app says, it could not fetch an access token.) So whatever is going wrong, it doesn’t seem to be going wrong in this step, but afterwards.

Comment: That is what I was thinking...  It is weird that is the error it is giving after it successfully redirected.  Do you have any ideas at all.  I have been looking at this for hours.  Feel like I am missing something small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I solved my own question...

I was thinking about @CBroa's comment above about the error message of invalid redirect happening after successful redirect.  This led me to look to see what was happening with the error message.

To get the error message I am doing:

```
$e->getPrevious()->getMessage()
```

This led me to believe that "getPrevious" was no longer relevant and maybe everything was working but I was accessing the token wrong. I am getting the token via:

```
Facebook::getTokenFromRedirect();
```

I did some research and found out this function is using the redirect url.  It was building the redirect URL wrong as localhost something.  This was returning null as it is not not my redirect url.

So reading futhur on how it was building this url I found in my app/config/app.php I had:

```
return array(

....

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application URL
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This URL is used by the console to properly generate URLs when using
| the Artisan command line tool. You should set this to the root of
| your application so that it is used when running Artisan tasks.
|
*/

'url' => 'http://localhost:8888',

 .....

 );
```

This is where the error was... I guess I never updated this after the initial Laravel install.  Upon fixing this to the correct URL I started to get the token.

Thank you everyone for you help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the app domain should just be yogijii.com, and the Site URL should just be yogijii.com

See:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11932194/1984156

Comment: changing the app domain and site url to yogijii.com had no effect.  I received the same error

Answer (score 0):

You set your Valid OAuth redirect URIs as `http://staging.breathe.yogijii.com/facebook/login/` so I'd want to believe you set your Website URL as `http://staging.breathe.yogijii.com/facebook/login/`

Your Website URL should be the spot where the login transaction finishes, it is for most intents and purposes your redirect URL.

Try it yourself by changing the redirect url from

https://www.facebook.com/v2.2/dialog/oauth?client_id=479112728894729&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fstaging.breathe.yogijii.com%2Ffacebook%2Flogin%2F&state=fd1c84414631fd179b3632f71cec9299&sdk=php-sdk-4.0.14&scope=email%2Cuser_status

to

https://www.facebook.com/v2.2/dialog/oauth?client_id=479112728894729&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fstaging.breathe.yogijii.com&state=fd1c84414631fd179b3632f71cec9299&sdk=php-sdk-4.0.14&scope=email%2Cuser_status

Comment: Thanks... I tried that... Turns out it was a problem in my application config in the laravel setup.  I was pointing to local host instead of my actual url.