# Facebook login from App subdomain not working

Tags: facebook, facebook-login, facebook-apps

I've set `domain.com` as one of my Facebook App domains. Facebook website login fails on one of its subdomains with this error message:

> Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings.  It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.

It's clear that login should be possible from a subdomain of an app domain, what is required to make this happen?

Comment: You might need to add those subdomain URLs as “Valid OAuth redirect URIs” under Settings->Advanced.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Facebook App on Subdomains: Site URL vs App Domains](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11932191/facebook-app-on-subdomains-site-url-vs-app-domains)