# How to permit facebook login by all pages and subdomains of the app?

Tags: javascript, facebook, fbsdk

I have many pages with subdomais by example: customer1.example.com, customer2.example.com, and i need to login users in all this domains and this subdomains are generated dynamically. In some point this used to work, but something is altered in facebook dashboard and this stopped to work.

I put oauth redirect and app domain to maindomain i tried other solutions like that [Facebook App on Subdomains: Site URL vs App Domains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11932191/facebook-app-on-subdomains-site-url-vs-app-domains). In this one says that is not possible [Facebook login from App subdomain not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31715044/facebook-login-from-app-subdomain-not-working), but last week this worked fine for us, i just need to discover what i need to do to correct that.

EDIT: When i try what tells in last post it works, but i have so many domains and they are generated automatically, making not so easy to maintain that.

Comment: There is not way to add Valid OAuth Redirect URIs via API. Your options are either to handle all login on example.com, and then redirect back to the customer specific subdomain afterwards; or manually inputting the URLs in the app settings.

Comment: But what i can do if the the users has many accounts, one per subdomain? Before i change the configs in the developer this works for all subdomains.

Comment: How does that change anything?